# Create a csv file on the fly and get url download using java

Tags: java, spring

how to create a csv file on the fly and get url for download that csv file ? i have try using java.io.file but that saving the file into storage, and i didn't want to save that file, just show the url for download that file

Comment: File needs a storage, where are you planning to store a file?

Comment: can it save temporary in memory until someone download that file ?

Comment: use some cloud storage like Amazon S3, for opensource see this https://www.minio.io/